# How to redirect to html page in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I am new to chrome extension.
I am creating an extension that will redirect to a custom HTML page whenever I open certain website.

I already tried `window.open`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`chrome.webRequest` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) will cover your needs.

After declaring permissions:

1. `"webRequest"` to activate the API
2. `"webRequestBlocking"` to be able to redirect requests
3. [Host permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns) for the page in question, e.g. `"http://example.com/"`

Then, in your background/event script you can add a listener with appropriate filters. Example:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  function(details) {
    return {redirectUrl: chrome.runtime.getURL("mypage.html")};
  },
  {urls: ["http://example.com/*"], types: ["main_frame", "sub_frame"]},
  ["blocking"]
);
```

See the docs for more details.